# When I download a 1.2G file from swift using python, it reports MemoryError

Tags: python-3.x, windows

I use vscode, The version of python is 3.7.3 64bit.

The code is

```
import swiftclient
from swiftclient.multithreading import OutputManager

conn = swiftclient.client.Connection(auth_version='1',user='admin:admin',key='admin9',authurl='http://172.16.101.79:6789/auth/v1.0')

container_name = 'storage2'

obj_tuple = conn.get_object(container_name, 'mu_visual_cpp_build_tools_2015_update_3_x86_dvd_779b35c8.iso')

with open('D:\\100\\mu_visual_cpp_build_tools_2015_update_3_x86_dvd_779b35c8.iso', 'wb+') as my_hello:
        my_hello.write(obj_tuple[1])
```

When I use this code to download the iso file from swift, it report memory error:

[image]

Then I'm checking Task Manager. VSCODE takes up 1.6G of memory.
[image]

Before this code was run, vscode took up 200M of memory.
My question is how to change the code to avoid vscode memory overflow

Comment: Surely there is an API that doesn't load the entire object into memory? Such that you can read buffers from it and write them to disk?

Comment: Thank you !  Which API ? Can you give me the  link of API doc ?

Comment: 'Surely there is an API' is a rhetorical question. I don't know the answer, but there must be. Anyway you certainly can't keep using this one, as it is apparent by inspection that it loads the entire download into memory before you can commit it to disk.

Answer (score -1):

## Source of the problem

You are trying to load large file into your memory, thats why you are getting this error. Since you are running this code from VSCode, it is running out of memory. VSCode has some memory limit. There is 2 solutions for this issue

### First Solution

This is the simplest solution, just run the python script in `command prompt`, If the file size is less than your available RAM, This method would work.

### Second Solution

I want you to refer to this docs
https://docs.openstack.org/python-swiftclient/ocata/swiftclient.html#swiftclient.client.get_object

According to this documentation, you can download the file in chunks

```
# Get the object from Swift in chunks
resp_headers, obj_iterator = conn.get_object(container_name, object_name, resp_chunk_size=65536)
```

By doing this you will not loading all content in memory once, so that memory error should go away